# Android: Why textView text attribute value is id?

Tags: android, textview, android-textattributes

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>
```

this is part code of ListActivity with custom Layout. So it can dynamically set value. Why android:text="@+id/label" ? Have a any other use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"   <-- wrong
    android:text="@string/label"   <-- get text from string.xml
    android:text="Label"     <-- direct text
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with ZeroOne's answer. Adding to him you said about dynamically changing value of textView
Inside your activity class

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
```

The id you used in you layout, you are using here to refer to it. You are using `R.id.label` because android has a

> auto generated `R.class`

files which has a unique hex code for all objects, string references, assets, layouts, colours, styles and IDs (most of them are final static) etc. So you are telling

> `R.id.label` (it's a resource ID of type int)

Go to R class -> Id  -> variable name

To set value to your textview

```
tv.setText("Hello World");
```

If in your layout file if you use

```
android:text="@+id/label"
```

It simply puts the value of text to set to textview as `@+id/label`. Which actually makes no sense unless you want to display `@+id/label` ..

If your plan is to set the value of textview as label in your layout file itself Then as ZeroOne said 
Either use

```
android:text="label"
```

Or

```
android:text="@string/my_label" // for this to work you need to add reference in strings.xml inside your res folder
```